# How can I create a Machine Learning API with Python Flask using a Large dataset approx 50GB

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, flask

I want to create an API where an user can enter some input, and the API (flask app)  will give me a predicted  result via machine learning (lin regression, k cluster).

Before it can predict a result, i need to train the data first. My dataset is pretty large, (around 50gb). So that means the app have to train the data everytime an user enters an input? This will take a long time right?

How can i work with large datasets using Flask for ML? So that the prediction goes fast?
And whats the best way to approach this? Using a ML for web apps?
I am new to this, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you need to retrain every time there is input?

Comment: Should i retrain it? I have no idea... I am pretty new to this, but what are the steps? So i train my data, and Python saves the trained data? And how should i train my data, via a cronjob? Can you explain me the steps? Thanks!

Comment: No, that's far too broad a question. But you almost certainly shouldn't be training again each time you get a new data point.

Comment: Another suggestion is to look for possible answers in [Data Science Stack Exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) as this current one is focused more to specific programming questions where you're expected to ask and provide code example as a context to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of questions besides the main one you are asking so I'll try to help with those as well. Before I try answering your main one let's go through couple of suggestions.

Just to make sure you are not reinventing the wheel:

- check if there are existing services that tho this particular thing:

  - ML on AWS https://aws.amazon.com/machine-learning/
  - ML on Azure https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/machine-learning/
  - AI/ML on GCloud https://cloud.google.com/products/ai/
- check if there are ways to use existing frameworks which let you deploy models to production

  - Tensorflow Serving https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tutorials/serving/rest_simple
  - Kubeflow https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/about/kubeflow/

If you still feel quite strong about your ML logic and want to pursue your own path into deployments to production then there are other considerations. I'm writing from my own experience, I did attempt something similar but not with such a large dataset.

How do you store your dataset, where do you keep it? This might be straightforward but it's not. Provided you run some sort of VM that reads the dataset, it needs to be close. Putting dataset in the same VM as ML code seems not like a great way to solve a problem (tight coupling, hard to quickly start/clone such VM), but putting it close in another container, such as S3 bucket or some separate VM on same network sounds plausible - low latency, simple topology, easy to hide from public.

Next is ML which executes long running tasks (training), and it is not suitable to be on a live server anyway as nobody will wait until it finishes processing 50GB. Would argue it is on separate VM as well which can scale on demand, ie you could just spawn 1 VM per each training request.

OK so now the problem is how to orchestrate all this? Without some async messaging capability it is quite hard (apart from scheduling). What I mean is it would be much easier for API server to send requests through something like Redis pub/sub or through AWS SNS and for your ML VM to process those requests one by one in background.

Flask API or any other API server would just be in the middle of this and would expose triggers to do ML learning and/or ML execution.

I think there is no simple answer to your question, but you can check out my approach to exposing simple Tensorflow script through Node.js (which is similar to Flask), training and then execution, it might help you in some way or another:

- Blog post about implementation: https://www.ivarprudnikov.com/run-tensorflow-scripts-nodejs-server-deployed-aws-docker-container/
- Github repo: https://github.com/ivarprudnikov/char-rnn-tensorflow